# Prove that $f'''(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I've been working on this problem for a bit and was hoping to get a hint.

**Problem:**

Suppose that $f$ is nonnegative and $f'''$ exists on $(0,1)$. Suppose also that there exist points $c \neq d$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f(c) = 0 = f(d)$. Prove that $f'''(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0,1)$.

**Attempt:**

Since $f'''$ exists on $(0,1)$, $f''$ and $f'$ exist and are continuous on $(0,1)$. By MVT and $f(c)=f(d)=0$, $\exists ~x \in (c,d)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$. Maybe this $x$ is my candidate for $f'''(x)=0$, but I'm not sure how to move forward.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ non negative implies that $c$ and $d$ are minimums and $f'(c)=f'(d)=0$. Let $e$ be the maximum of $f$ in $[c,d]$, $f'(e)=0$ (we suppose $f(e)\neq 0$ otherwise the restriction of $f$ to $[c,d]$ is zero and the result is true). There exists $a\in (c,e)$ with $f"(a)=0$ (since $f'(c)=f'(e)=0$) and $b\in (e,d)$ with $f"(b)=0$ so there exists $u\in (a,b)$ with $f'''(u)=0$.

Comment: $f$ need not have a maximum, I suppose.

Comment: $f$ is continuous and not identically zero on the interval $[c,d]$, so it must have a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily note that $c, d$ are local minima of $f$ and hence $f'(c) =f'(d) =0$. And since $f(c) =f(d) =0$, by Rolle's theorem we have a point $p\in(c, d) $ such that $f'(p) =0$. Now $f'(c) =f'(p)=f'(d) =0$ and hence Rolle's theorem gives us $a\in(c, p), b\in(p, d) $ such that $f''(a) =f''(b) =0$ and again applying Rolle's theorem we get $f'''(q) =0$ for some $q\in(a, b) \subseteq (0,1)$.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here. Very elegant, too.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: thanks for the appreciation. The key fact here is observation that $c, d$ are local extrema. Apart from that I think rest follows quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f'(c)=0$. If $f''(c)\ne 0$, then $f'''(c)=0$. Similarly for $d$.

So let's assume $f''(c) > 0$, $f''(d) > 0$. Then $c,d$ are local minima.

So there must be a local maximum in $(c, d)$, at which, again, either the third derivative is zero, or the second derivative is negative.

Because $f''(c)>0$ or $f''(d)>0$, and $f''(a)<0$, then by mean value theorem, there exists a point at which the third derivative is zero.